# Set backgroung color of input in case of an error

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a problem with knockout and validating. I would like to color my input when an error occurs.

The problem is that when I use the knockout.validation library from github, there is an error:

```
{"error": "Please use POST request"}
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/kd2haczL/3/

```
ko.validation.configure({
     insertMessages: false,
     decorateElement: true,
     errorElementClass: 'error'
       });
```

And when I use from CDN, there is no error, but coloring doesn't work.

see: http://jsfiddle.net/kd2haczL/1/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSFiddle is unable to execute the knockout source directly from github - check console: "because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

Your second example with CDN has `<style>` tags in CSS field. As your form value is bound to model.toValidate() you could modify the self.validate1 function as follows:

```
self.validate1 = function () {
    self.toValidate(self.toValidate() || '');
};
```

like so: http://jsfiddle.net/81cL4xjk/2/